# Remove some elements in one dictionary based on another

Tags: python

Suppose I got two dictionaries like this.

```
a  = {'file1': [('1.txt', 1.0),
                ('3.txt', 0.4),
                ('2.txt', 0.3)],
      'file2': [('1.txt', 0.5),
                ('2.txt', 0.2),
                ('3.txt', 1.0)]}

b =  {'file1': [('1.txt', 9),
                ('2.txt', 1),
                ('3.txt', 5),
                ('4.txt', 4)],
      'file2': [('1.txt', 0),
                ('2.txt', 2),
                ('3.txt', 3),
                ('4.txt', 0)]}
```

I wrote a function to filter the dictionary b base on dictionary a.

The expecting result of the function is like:

```
c =  {'file1': [('1.txt', 9),
                ('2.txt', 1),
                ('3.txt', 5)],
      'file2': [('1.txt', 0),
                ('2.txt', 2),
                ('3.txt', 3)]
```

So far I've wrote a function but it's output isn't that one I want.

```
def filter():
    c = {file1:set((txt1,value2)
               for file1,dic1 in a.items()
               for file2,dic2 in b.items()
               for txt1,value1 in dic1
               for txt2,value2 in dic2
               if txt1 == txt2 and file1 == file2)
         for file1,dic1 in a.items()}

    pp({k:v for k,v in c.items()})
```

The output now is shown below:

```
{'file1': {('1.txt', 0),
           ('1.txt', 9),
           ('2.txt', 1),
           ('2.txt', 2),
           ('3.txt', 3),
           ('3.txt', 5)},
 'file2': {('1.txt', 0),
           ('1.txt', 9),
           ('2.txt', 1),
           ('2.txt', 2),
           ('3.txt', 3),
           ('3.txt', 5)}}
```

I dont know where went wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for such tasks :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in b.items():
...      for i in v:
...         if i[0] in zip(*a[k])[0]: #in python 3 next(zip(*a[k]))
...              d[k].append(i)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'file2': [('1.txt', 0), ('2.txt', 2), ('3.txt', 3)], 'file1': [('1.txt', 9), ('2.txt', 1), ('3.txt', 5)]})
```

*Note* that for checking the existence of `b` values in a you can get the file names with [*zip*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function!

Also as a another way you can use [*dict.setdefault() method*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) :

```
>>> c={}
>>> for k,v in b.items():
...      for i in v:
...         if i[0] in zip(*a[k])[0]:
...            c.setdefault(k,[]).append(i)
... 
>>> c
{'file2': [('1.txt', 0), ('2.txt', 2), ('3.txt', 3)], 'file1': [('1.txt', 9), ('2.txt', 1), ('3.txt', 5)]}
```

*Note* : if you are using python3 as the `zip` function return a generator you cannot index it so you need to change `zip(*a[k])[0]:` to `next(zip(*a[k])):`

Comment: How do u know about these functions?

Comment: I putted the link on answer you can read about it on documentation!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/a.py", line 27, in <module>
    filter()
  File "C:/Python34/a.py", line 23, in filter
    if i[0] in zip(*a[k])[0]:
TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @programlover welcome, i also added a solution with `dict.setdefault`, and if it was helpful you can accept the answer ;)

Comment: maybe it can change to :if i[0] in (a[k])[0]:

Comment: @programlover are you using python 3?

Comment: sry i see . Yeah it words. Thank u very much

Comment: @programlover so what about the accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am new learner as well and my answer is not nearly as good as the one before, but since I spent some time solving the problem :) my code is

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(data, flt):
    newflt = {}
    for k, v in flt.items():
        newflt[k] = map(lambda t: t[0], v)
    outd = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in data.items():
        fv = newflt[k]
        for t in v:
            if t[0] in fv:
                outd[k].append(t)
    return outd
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep common keys with common values where you have uncommon keys:

```
print({k:[v for v in val if v[0] in {x[0] for x in a[k]}] for k, val in b.items() if k in a})

{'file2': [('1.txt', 0), ('2.txt', 2), ('3.txt', 3)], 'file1': [('1.txt', 9), ('2.txt', 1), ('3.txt', 5)]}
```

If you have uncommon keys and also want to keep those keys and values:

```
print({k:([v for v in val if v[0] in {x[0] for x in a[k]}] if k in a else val) for k, val in b.items()})

{'file2': [('1.txt', 0), ('2.txt', 2), ('3.txt', 3)], 'file1': [('1.txt', 9), ('2.txt', 1), ('3.txt', 5)]}
```

If you want to actually filter the **original** dict:

```
for k, val in b.items():
    b[k] = [v for v in val if v[0] in {x[0] for x in a[k]}]

print(b)
```

Or a dict comp to create a new dict if all keys are common:

```
print({k:[v for v in val if v[0] in {x[0] for x in a[k]}]  for k, val in b.items()})

{'file2': [('1.txt', 0), ('2.txt', 2), ('3.txt', 3)], 'file1': [('1.txt', 9), ('2.txt', 1), ('3.txt', 5)]}
```

filtering the original dict will be by far the most efficient.